# Why is my answer in the negatives when I did research and provided a video copy?

Tags: discussion, abuse

[Can you dye a Snow Golem?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/126336/can-you-dye-a-snow-golem)

My answer has a negative review. I did research. I enacted the research. I answered. Yet people aren't satisfied with a reasonable answer. Why is that?

Comment: I'm on the fence on this question. On one hand, that video is definitive proof; you can't to dye a snow golem. On the other, the text indicates that the reason you can't apply dyes to snowmen is *because* snow blocks cannot be dyed. That statement just doesn't seem to make sense. You might argue that the base texture for the snowman's body and head are derived from existing blocks, so without pre-existing textures for coloured snow, it is not feasible to dye the golem. I'd counter that not all art assets that make up the golem are tied to existing things, like the 'buttons'.

Comment: @TrentHawkins And leather can't be dyed, yet you can dye leather armour just fine. Leather armour has no coloured art assets either. (Dying leather graphics are accomplished directly in code.) You're right that the lack of art assets doesn't prove the point in either direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that it's due to the elaboration "You can't dye snow golems because you can't dye snow." That implies a whole host of other dyable/not dyable things that don't necessarily work in Minecraft.

By the way, I'd upvoted that post when I first saw it because it seemed like you proved the question conclusively, regardless of the questionable assumption you drew from it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you had to post a meta question to ask this when there has been a comment under your answer from the same day which tells you the problem with it:

> That... logic makes no sense.

It has 13 upvotes right now, indicating that the answer could potentially have 10 more downvotes if people weren't being polite and refraining from piling on. Consider fixing the broken logical statement in the answer if you would like people to reconsider those downvotes.